# Elasticsearch Java API cannot ignore null or empty values

Tags: java, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using the new-to-me Spring Elasticsearch API which [no longer supports Jackson serialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch-migration-guide-3.2-4.0).  I'm in the process of updating all my entities, but have run into an issue where I can no longer ignore properties that have a null or empty value when serializing.

Can someone help point me to some documentation for the new Java API that mimics the Jackson `@JsonInclude(Include.NonNull, Include.NonEmpty)` annotation, which ONLY includes the property when its value is NOT null and NOT empty.

I've looked all over the web, but I cannot find any hints as to how this can be accomplished.

Any links or insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which new Java Elasticsearch API? Are you talking about the new client (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java)? The link you posted refers to a change in Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0 thas was made more than 2 years ago. Spring Data Elasticsearch does not send `null` values to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Yes, we updated our version of spring-data-elasticsearch and are now facing this issue.  I'm trying to NOT serialize a property if it's value is null or empty, just like an annotation from Jackson

Comment: The value which I'm specifically referring to is of type Map and does get serialized as EMPTY.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to solve the issue I describe above:

`Foo` Entity

```
public class Foo {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Nullable
    @Field(type = FieldType.Object)
    private Map<String, Object> map1;

    @Nullable
    @Field(type = FieldType.Object)
    private Map<String, Object> map2;

       // getter and setter
}
```

Code to populate `Foo`

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.setId("42");
foo.setMap1(null);
foo.setMap2(new LinkedHashMap<>());
operations.save(foo);
```

The following gets sent to Elastic

`{"_class":"com.package.to.Foo","id":"42","map2":{}}`

A `BeforeConvertCallback` class that turns initialized, but empty, values to null preventing them from being sent to elastic.

```
@Component
public class FooBeforeConvertCallback implements BeforeConvertCallback<Foo> {

    @Override
    public Foo onBeforeConvert(Foo foo, IndexCoordinates indexCoordinates) {


        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(foo.getMap1())) {
            foo.setMap1(null);
        }

        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(foo.getMap2())) {
            foo.setMap2(null);
        }
        return foo;
    }
}
```

This solution will *ONLY* work for the entity `Foo`.